# Cart con laravel, error Property [product_id] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel

hice una webapp en laravel y estoy tratando de hacer una view para el usuario con el resumen del pedido, en donde aparezca una lista con los productos que agrego al carrito, los datos del usuario y el punto de entrega elegido. El tema es que cuando quiero mostrar los datos del carrito me sale este error "Property [product_id] does not exist on this collection instance".
Las otras variables me andan bien, ya las probé. Los datos estan almacenados en una base de datos, en la tabla carrito que tiene una forgein key para enlazar los productos... subo captura del controller al que le puse resumen y a la view

[image: Controller]

[image: view]

aca agrego una captura de lo que seria el metodo en el controller del arrito que use para mostrar en la view del carrito, los elementos

[image: controller del cart]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, saludos y gracias

Comment: Hola. Esta es una página de código, no de capturas de pantalla. A menos que subas el código como texto, no vas a recibir respuestas a tu pregunta. Si tengo que intentar reproducir tu error, me toca escribir todo tu código a mano en vez de cortar y pegar y la verdad, no estoy dispuesto a hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno amigo lo primero que te diria para solucionar tu problemas es que intentes debug a mano, coloca algunos var_dump() o dd() conforme a lo que necesitas validar para saber que valores traen tus variables sobre todo esas que dice carrito.

Lo segundo es que estas siendo redundante `Auth::user()` ya trae el usuario con sus datos no es necesario volver ha hacer la busqueda.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: ya hice un dd, carrito me trae me trae el product_id, al final me di cuenta lo tenia que traer como un atriburto del carrito y no era necesario que lo guarde en una variable... y arregle lo del Auth::user(), todavia estoy aprendiendo y no me doy cuenta de estas cosas :p, gracias

Comment: Excelente, no olvides siempre hacer debug de los valores que estan tomando tus variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos errores con tu código, en primera, al parecer lo que te devuelve `$user->carrito` es una colección, por lo tanto no puedes poner `$cart->producto_id`, tendrías que iterar sobre la variable `$cart` en tu vista:

```
@foreach($cart as $producto)
   {{-- HTML aquí.... --}}
@endforeach
```

El otro error es que en tu vista estás iterando sobre una variable `$productos`, la cual, no estás enviando en ningún momento, pero bueno, a fin de cuenta la que tienes que enviar sería `$cart`: `->with(['cart' => $cart]);`.

Como observación también te comento que no es necesario que coloques un `with` tras otro por cada variable que desees enviar, dentro del mismo array puedes enviar todas las que quieras:

```
->with(['datoUsuario' => $datoUsuario, 'punto' => $punto, 'cart' => $cart]);
```

También puedes usar la función `compact` de PHP que te evita escribir el array.

```
->with(compact('datoUsuario', 'punto', 'cart'));
```

Aunque para mi gusto si vas a enviar muchas variables a una vista preferiría mandar un array con todas las que necesite:

```
$datos = array();
$datos['datoUsuario'] = $datoUsuario;
$datos['punto'] = $punto;
$datos['cart'] = $cart;

->with(compact('datos'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, me estaba complicando al divino boton. El codigo del controller quedo asi:

```
  public function index()
    {

      $datoUsuario =Auth::user();

      $productos=$datoUsuario->carrito; (es una consulta pivot que esta en el model del usuario)

       return view('/resumen/index')->with(['datoUsuario' => $datoUsuario],['productos'=> 
       $productos]);
    }
```